# Passing a parameter to a ROS Timer callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a ROS Timer callback using boost bind as I'd have done it for a subscriber callback but it's not working for me.

Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    int my_arg = 0;
    node.createTimer(ros.Duration(1.0),
                     boost::bind(&MyClass::callback, this, _1, _2, my_arg),
                     true); //for oneshot
}

void MyClass::callback(int arg)
{
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("callback: " << arg);
}
```

But this is not compiling:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: ‘void (MyClass::*)(int)’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41343/passing-a-parameter-to-a-ros-timer-callback/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bind call should match the function signature. You'll have to remove the _1, _2 part from the bind call.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1